# NPM Windows doesn't execute program under the User Variable path

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

So I have npm and installed gulp globally. `gulp.cmd` is available under `%Appdata%/npm` and it had added the `NODE_PATH` user variable.

When I type in `gulp` in my command prompt, it returns `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command.` But it **is**! It is in `%Appdata%/npm`.

Why is that? I've checked and the links are valid and I can execute gulp like so `%node_path%/gulp`

Comment: The directory containing `gulp` is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Shouldn't I still be able to execute programs from user variable paths?

Comment: No. Read the duplicate question.

Comment: @DavidPostill this question is no where near similar with the question this is marked duplicate of...

Comment: Yes it is. It explains what a path is and tell you how to add things to the path. I already told you "The directory containing gulp is not in your PATH"

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm sorry, but my IQ is approaching 0, I can't seem to find something like "command prompt will not execute programs in any user variables paths" in the linked question. Mind to enlighten me?

Comment: `echo %path%` will show you what is in your path. Is `%Appdata%/npm` in that list? Is `%node_path%/gulp` in that list?

Comment: @DavidPostill `%Appdata%/npm` is the value of `NODE_PATH`, the user variable. I might want to rephrase the question to: Can command prompt run programs in user variable paths.

Comment: <sigh> No. The command prompt will execute programs in the PATH. Not some user defined variable **unless you add that to the PATH**.

Comment: You can add `%Appdata%/npm` or `%node_path%` to the PATH **as explained in the dupe question

Comment: @DavidPostill Then I feel terribly sorry for not being familiar with Windows. However, I still insist that this question is not the same as the linked one because we had different intentions. Thanks.